# Replace C Oracle backend with Redis or with CSV files

Tags: c, redis, io

In current setup

1. Take a file from FTP location
2. Assign a thread for it
3. Process the file
4. Insert data to an Oracle table
5. If file processing failed replay the file

The complete program written in C. Now there is a requirement to replace Oracle part with CSV files. Two thoughts writing to files directly. Here the worry is I/O operation time. The other option is writing to a Redis with a key of file name and dump the Redis key data to file from a separate program.

Are there any better approach or path available ? System is a critical and high performant system.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but maybe simpler to use an external table to load the data? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/examples-using-oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-53C71354-FDC0-4CD7-BBF1-2B7327A1A245

Comment: The requirement is to replace Oracle DB with CSV files